# Why am I getting a gapi.client undefined error?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm starting to use Google APIs. I have a web app that I'd like to connect to google calendar. I'm using the following example, just to get the hang of things:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function appendResults(text) {
        console.log("***** DEBUG_jwir3: Appending results...");
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        results.appendChild(document.createElement('P'));
        results.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
      }

      function makeRequest() {
        console.log("***** DEBUG_jwir3: Making request...");
        var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.get({
          'shortUrl': 'http://goo.gl/fbsS'
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
          appendResults(response.longUrl);
        });
      }

      function load() {
        console.log("***** DEBUG_jwir3: Loading....");
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyDkiyjtUnxlzQUyxnu0WqUtkhyV8Q2KyA0');
        gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', makeRequest);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Most of this code is taken directly from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#LoadinganAPIandMakingaRequest but I modified it a bit to output some data about what's going on. I am getting the following:

```
GET https://apis.google.com/js/client.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 71ms]
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. test.html
GET https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.pjG1qAV7lig.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AItRSTOwlG0qQ6tB8ZQLSqOIeICvIpAiTw/cb=gapi.loaded_0 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 657ms]
TypeError: gapi.client is undefined test.html:23
GET https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.pjG1qAV7lig.O/m=debug_error/exm=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AItRSTOwlG0qQ6tB8ZQLSqOIeICvIpAiTw/cb=gapi.loaded_1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 44ms]
"***** DEBUG_jwir3: Loading...." test.html:22
TypeError: c is undefined
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on here. I've enabled the urlshortener API in my google developer console. Also, I'm running this from a localhost machine, so my understanding is that all localhost or file:// referrer requests should be allowed. I did make my API key allow all referrers, though, with a wildcard: *.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: One other thing I forgot to mention - if I look at the requests/responses, I get the javascript for the google client APIs, which start by defining gapi.client, so I'm not sure why it thinks its undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This  could be due to your browser blocking cookies from google.com.

I have Firefox permanently set to block cookies unless I specifically whitelist a site. With google.com blocked by default, I get a blank Google Calendar with the errors you report, but with cookies allowed for google.com the calendar shows.

Comment: Specifically Google requires *third party cookies* which are usually associated with advertising trackers.